# How can only output the Location line in a curl | grep pipeline?

Tags: shell, curl

In my terminal:

```
curl wttr.in/hak | grep Location
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  8827  100  8827    0     0  25438      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 25438
Location: Республика Хакасия, Сибирский федеральный округ, Россия [53.4399379,90.0664303]
```

How get the only Location line?

```
Location: Республика Хакасия, Сибирский федеральный округ, Россия [53.4399379,90.0664303]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-s` flag:

```
$ curl -s wttr.in/hak | grep Location
Location: Республика Хакасия, Сибирский федеральный округ, Россия [53.4399379,90.0664303]
```